# Learning a new language using broken unit tests

Tags: programming-languages, learning, tools, unit-testing

I was listening to a dot net rocks the other day where they mentioned, almost in passing, a really intriguing tool for learning new languages -- I think they were specifically talking about F#.

It's a solution you open up and there are a bunch of broken unit tests. Fixing them walks you through the steps of learning the language.

I want to check it out, but I was driving in my car and I have no idea what the name of the project is or which dot net rocks episode it was. Google hasn't helped much. Any idea?

Comment: Cool idea -- definitely hope someone can find the reference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are looking for the various 'koans' projects, started at [EdgeCase](https://web.archive.org/web/20150524111945/http://www.edgecase.com:80/). To learn what a '[koan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C5%8Dan)' is refer to Wikipedia, but the general idea is you are confronted with a challenge (a failing unit test) and your journey to enlightenment (learning the programming language) comes from overcoming challenges on your journey.

See:

- [Ruby koans](http://rubykoans.com/)
- [Python koans](https://web.archive.org/web/20171017085456/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/gregorymalcolm/archive/2010/04/05/koans-now-available-in-python-flavor.aspx)

People are working on the koans for [other languages](https://github.com/relevance/functional-koans#readme), like F#, however they are not as far along as Ruby and Python.